# Smooth family of metrics

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, lipschitz-functions

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $(g(t))_{t\in[a,b]}$ be a family of complete Riemannian metrics (on $M$) that smoothly depend on $t$.

If $x$ and $y$ are two arbitrary points on $M$, we can define a distance function $f(t):=d_{g(t)}(x,y)$ that varies through time. The distance $d_{g(t)}$ is the usual distance induced by the Riemannian  metric $g(t)$.

What I am interested in is the regularity of the function $f$, and specifically I want to use the Rademacher's theorem which guarantees me that $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable on $M$ if I can prove that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous or at least locally Lipschitz continuous.

A first idea is to use the completeness of $M$ to deduce that there is a minimising unit-speed geodesic $\gamma_t$ between $x$ and $y$ at any time, so we write :
$$d_{g(t)}(x,y)=L_{g(t)}(\gamma_t)$$
But I can't prove why the family of minimising geodesic $(\gamma_t)$ would also depend smoothly on time. Moreover, I want to also prove an explicit formula for the derivative (when $f$ is differentiable ) which is :
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t_0}d_{g(t)}(x,y)=L_{g(t_0)}(\gamma_{t_0})$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As written, $f$ is a function of $t$, not of $x,y$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, x and y are fixed.

Comment: @Moishe: really? What about two antipodal points on a sphere?